# calculating prime factors in 'R'

Tags: r, factors

I am very new to 'R' and am trying to start learning it. I have written the following program to generate the prime factors of a given number. But for mysterious reasons it generates a nonsense list at the end of the day. I cannot find where or why this is happening. Please can you help.

```
library(gmp)
getPrimeFactors = function(n){
    primeList=c()
    if(isprime(n)){
        primeList <- append(primeList, n)
        return (primeList)
    }
    currentPrime <- 2
    while(TRUE){
        # Check if input is divisible by the current primeList
        if(n %% currentPrime == 0){
            cat(sprintf("the number %f is divisible by %f\n", n, currentPrime))
            n = n%/%currentPrime
            cat(sprintf("current prime :%f\n", currentPrime))
            primeList = append(primeList,currentPrime)
            currentPrime = 2
            if(isprime(n)){
                primeList <- append(primeList, n)
                return (primeList)
            }
        }
        else{
            #cat(sprintf("the number %f is NOT divisible by %f\n", n, currentPrime))
            #cat(sprintf("current prime before is: %f\n", currentPrime))
            print(c("current prime before:", currentPrime))
            currentPrime = nextprime(currentPrime)
            #cat(sprintf("current prime after is: %f\n", currentPrime))
            print(c("current prime after:", currentPrime))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `factorize` from the same package?

Comment: What is your expected output ? Is your goal to write yourself this function or are you just looking to get all the divisors ?

Comment: for the input 18, I was hoping for an output of 2,3,3. But I get:2 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 3 0 0 0. I now know there is already a factorize function but I still would like to know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `nextprime(currentPrime)` doesn't return a base R numeric value. It returns a value with class bigz. Look at the output of `cat(nextprime(2)`.
To fix your code change the line

```
currentPrime = nextprime(currentPrime)
```

to

```
currentPrime = as.numeric(nextprime(currentPrime))
```

Comment: Thank you. My sanity is restored. How foolish of me to think that nextprime would return an integer :) That will teach me not to check the documentation before calling an unknown function.